# Generic method, multiple brackets, types

Tags: java, generics

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genmethods.html
Quoting from there-

> A more realistic use of generic methods might be something like the following, which defines a static method that stuffs references to a single item into multiple boxes:
>
> ```
> public static <U> void fillBoxes(U u, List<Box<U>> boxes) { 
> for (Box<U> box: boxes {
>   box.add(u); }
> ```
>
> }

Here, what does this `List<Box<U>>` do? How does this work?

Further,

> To use this method, your code would look something like the following:
>
> ```
>  Crayon red = ...;
>  List<Box<Crayon>> crayonBoxes = ...;
>
> The complete syntax for invoking this method is:
>
> Box.<Crayon>fillBoxes(red, crayonBoxes);
> ```

I couldn't understand all these.

Comment: I don't know what you don't understand.  Can you say what you specificity don't know so we can answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List is a generic collection.
Box is another generic.

You can declare `Box<Crayon>` to construct a Box of Crayons

`List<Box>` is a collection of Boxes but Box is generic, need a Type for the box `List<Box<Crayon>>`.

Just follow the generic type U. FillBoxes method is static `public static <U> void fillBoxes(U u, List<Box<U>> boxes)`. Static methods doesn't need a instance, if there is not a instance you can't declare the type of the box `Box<Crayon>`, you have to pass the type in the call of the method `Box.<Crayon>fillBoxes`, knowing that type, the compiler knows that the first parameter in FillBoxes (`U u`) is a Crayon type and the second is a List of Boxes of Crayons (`List<Box<U>> boxes`).

The method will fill a list of Crayon Boxes with red crayons :)

Ufff this was hard for a non Java programmer and non native english speaker...

Answer (score 3):

You can think of U as a kind of placeholder for a Type or Interface.
If you have a class Foo and replace all U's in the method declaration with Foo, it will take an instance of Foo and a List>.
As the name "Generic" says, it is a generic way of "replacing" the generic type argument U with a real type. This way you can force that everyone who uses an object of Type U also has to use a List> to call the method.
Taking the Foo example, I can only call

```
public static <U> void fillBoxes(U u, List<Box<U>> boxes) {
```

with

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
List<Box<Foo>> fooList = new ArrayList<Box<Foo>>();
fillBoxes(foo, fooList);
```

Answer (score 1):

`List<Box<U>>` simply means it's a list of boxes where you can store U-type objects in each of them.

If for example you have classes "crayon", "pencil", "pen" etc. implementing interface "U", you can store their instances in such boxes.